# How can we import the gnuplot output in LaTeX?

Tags: floats, gnuplot

I am using the `gnuplot` and create the `myploy.tex` as following:

```
set terminal epslatex   
set output 'mplot.tex'   
set xlabel "Avg. No. of demand duration (slot) "   
set ylabel "Acceptence rate (%)"   
set grid xtics ytics   
set key right bottom   

set style line 1 lw 1 lc 3 pt 7  
set style line 2 lw 1 lc 1 pt 5  
set style line 3 lw 1 lc 0 pt 9  
set style line 4 lw 1 lc 4 pt 3  

plot "AcceptanceRate_Ser.txt" using 2:4:5:6 title "NoMig" with errorlines linestyle 1,\ 
     "AcceptanceRate_Ser.txt" using 2:7:8:9 title "FlowMig" with errorlines linestyle 2 ,\ 
      "AcceptanceRate_Ser.txt" using 2:10:11:12 title "VMMig" with errorlines linestyle 3, \ 
     "AcceptanceRate_Ser.txt" using 2:13:14:15 title "NoRis" with errorlines linestyle 4
```

Finally, I have `myplot.tex` and `myplot.eps`.

I need to import them in the LaTeX file as figure I did the following:

```
\begin{figure}[!]  
\begin{center}  
\input{myplot.tex}  
\caption{Graph caption}  
\label{graph:graph1}  
\end{center}    
\end{figure}
```

and used the following package:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}  
\usepackage{txfonts}  
\usepackage{epstopdf}
```

but I can't.

Comment: You can use `gnuplottex` and use gnuplot code directly in your tex file. Also, `pgfplots` integrates `gnuplot` seemlessly.

Comment: "but I can't". Can you give more details. Are you using the "-shell-escape" option? (to run `epstopdf`).

Answer (score 9):

Here are the methods that allow us to use `gnuplot` directly inside the `.tex` file.

**Using `gnuplottex`:**

```
%% compile with 'pdflatex --shell-escape myfile.tex'
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[miktex]{gnuplottex}  %% I am using miktex
\begin{document}
\begin{gnuplot}[terminal=pdf,terminaloptions=color]
    unset key
    set samples 10000
    set format '%g'
    set xlabel "Avg. No. of demand duration (slot) "
    set ylabel "Acceptence rate (%)"
    set xrange [-6:6]
    set yrange [0:0.41]
    f(n,x) = gamma(.5*(n+1))/(sqrt(n*pi)*gamma(.5*n))*((1+x**2/n)**(-.5*(n+1)))
    plot for[i=1:20] f(i,x)
\end{gnuplot}
%
\end{document}
```

**Using `pgfplots`**  (code from manual):

```
%% compile with 'pdflatex --shell-escape myfile.tex'
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot gnuplot {sin(x)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Both need to be compiled with `--shell-escape` option and you can use `pdflatex` directly.

Comment: These are two further methods, not *the methods*, and the one used in the question is also valid to include `gnuplot` output.

Answer (score 6):

Since you have not included the output and errors produced, it is hard to determine exactly what is wrong.

However, your problem could be that you don't have 
`\usepackage{colors}` in your preamble.

EDIT: 
Looking at it again it could also be that you added `.tex` when using the `\input`-command. I believe

```
\input{myplot.tex}
```

should have been

```
\input{myplot}
```

END OF EDIT.

To try something a little simpler than the sought solution, you can try to have gnuplot output a tex-document that will compile by it self. The following code does that.

```
set terminal epslatex size 9cm,7cm standalone
set output 'test.tex'

unset key
plot x**2;
```

Then running `latex test.tex` and `dvipdf test.dvi`, you get a pdf looking like this:
[image: x**2]

Looking at the produced `test.tex` file you will see that it is including the LaTeX pakcages *graphicx*, *color* and *geometry*. I would start making sure I have those included in my main document as well.

To see if I can the gnuplot-generated graph I make a new tex-file `comp_test.tex` with the content:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \begin{center}
    \include{test}
  \end{center}
  \caption{A caption}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

and I make sure to remove the part of the gnuplot-file that says `standalone`:

```
set terminal epslatex 
set output 'test.tex'

unset key
plot x**2;
```

Now running `gnuplot test.gnu`, `latex comp_test.tex`, `dvipdf comp_test.dvi` I get a pdf that looks like this:
[image: x**2 graph included in latex]

If you would like to read more about gnuplot I would strongly recommend visiting 
[http://gnuplotting.org](http://www.gnuplotting.org/). I learned about the LaTeX-terminal specifically from this article http://www.gnuplotting.org/tag/epslatex/.

Good luck.

Comment: I copied your solution. 1: Created a new gnuplot script and include the 4 lines of gnuplot code you gave. I ran this with gnuplot. 2: I copied and pasted the latex commands into a new texstudio document and compiled it. I got a load of errors, the first of which is "missing } inserted". Any ideas what is wrong?

Comment: I am finding this very frustrating as nothing I seem to try is working, and i have tried many different latex like terminals etc, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Okay I've sorted it - the problem is I was being a moron.